# A variation of weighted interval scheduling

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem and it ultimately boils down to this : Given a set of weighted intervals S , I am trying to find the minimum number of intervals in S such that they span a predefined, presumable larger, interval I and has the maximum weight. Firstly, it looks like we can reduce the set cover problem to this problem, but the continuity of the intervals is means the sets also has to be 'continous' ? Or is the problem multi-objective ?

Comment: Do you want minimum number or maximum weight? Or of all with the minimum number, find maximal weight?

Comment: Finding maximum weight alone is trivial .The solution set  will contain all the intervals intersecting with I. I need the minimum number that will span across the interval I and if there are more than 1  solutions, then I will prefer the one with maximum weight.

Comment: So you need the minimal number of intervals that fully cover the whole `I`, and out of all such solutions, the one that maximized the weight?

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This problem at least allows for a simple dynamic programming solution.

Consider all endpoints of your segments. Order them by the coordinate.

For each endpoint `X`, calculate the minimum number of segments to cover the whole interval from the start of `I` (denote this start as `S`) to this point `X`. Do it as follows: iterate over all segments that cover the point `X`. For each segment try to take it to your solution. Then you have to cover the interval from `S` to the start of this segment with minimal number of segments, and of all such solution with maximal weight --- you have calculated this answer earlier in your dynamic programming. So now after you iterated over all segments, just pick the best solutions.

Something like (pseudocode)

```
crop all given segments if they stretch outside of I, now each segment lies in I
sort all endpoints of your segments, assume X is the sorted array and L its length
if (X[0]!=I.left) or (X[L]!=I.right)
    no solution is availavle
answer[0] = 0
weight[0] = 0
for i=1..L
    answer[i] = infinity
    for j=0..N (the number of segments)
        if (X[i]>=segment[j].left) and (X[i]<=segment[j].right)
            p = position of segment[j].left in X (can be precalculated)
            candidate_answer = answer[p] + 1
            candidate_weight = weight[p] + segment[j].weight
            if (candidate_answer<answer[i]) or (
                  (candidate_answer==answer[i]) and (candidate_weigth>weight[i]))
                answer[i] = candidate_answer
                weight[i] = candidate_weight
answer[L] and weight[L] is your answer
```

This is `O(N^2)`. Maybe a faster solution exists, but I can not think of one now.